# Moderated mediation index significant but c path not significant

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, interaction, spss, mediation

I ran process 14 for my study, which has one categorical IV (crisis type), blame as the mediator and negative word of mouth as DV. The relevance of the crisis event plays the role of a moderator in the model. My results show that moderated mediation index is significant, yet the mediation paths were insignificant at different points of the moderator. Then how can I interpret this result? Can I still say it is a moderated mediation model?[image]

Comment: Is the moderated mediation actually significant? The CI intersects 0, so I would have thought not. And if it is technically significant, the CI intersecting 0 would give me pause.

Comment: Than you so much!